# Is there a way to validate international phone number in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-country-code

I am using flutter country_code_picker 1.4.0 package to get the dial code, Is there any way to validate international phone number by length.

[country_code_picker package](https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Comment: Thanks, but no it's not the answer..i found the another package

Comment: whats that package?

Comment: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/international_phone_input

Comment: Any alternative that support web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was on comment section, I am mentioning that here,

[International phone number input validation](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/international_phone_input)

Above package is the only way of I found to validate International phone number flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

NOTE: only 10 digit validate. by below method.

```
String validateMobile(String value) {
  String pattern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);

  if (value.length == 0) {
      return 'Please enter mobile number';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Please enter valid mobile number';
  }

  return null;
}
```